# SPARQL Unresolved prefixed name

Tags: xml, sparql, rdf

Hello there and thank you in advance for your help! :)

I am trying to write some SPARQL queries (new to the subject) and I am obviously doing something wrong regarding the prefixes, so I am getting this error message " Unresolved prefixed name ..."
I would greatly appreciate any help.
Here is my code:

```
PREFIX admission: <http://fake.nhs.ed.ac.uk/2016/10/data/fake-admission#>
PREFIX admissioncode: <http://fake.nhs.ed.ac.uk/2016/10/data/fake-admission-code#>
PREFIX diagnosis: <http://fake.nhs.ed.ac.uk/2016/10/data/fake-diagnosis#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX nhsfake: <http://fake.nhs.ed.ac.uk/2016/10/data/core#>
PREFIX ns1: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX patient: <http://fake.nhs.ed.ac.uk/2016/10/data/fake-patient#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX specialty: <http://fake.nhs.ed.ac.uk/2016/10/data/fake-specialty#>
PREFIX waitinglist: <http://fake.nhs.ed.ac.uk/2016/10/data/fake-waitinglist#>
PREFIX xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

#Q1
select ?specialtyid ?specialtyname
where {
?specialty a :nhsfake:Specialty ;
:specialty:specialtyid ?specialtyid ;
:specialty:specialtyname  ?specialtyname .
}
```

The query is supposed to run on a .ttl file, and I am using

```
arq --query=queries.rq --data=fake_data.ttl
```

With Jena

Thanks again!

Comment: prefixes have to be called without the colon in front of the prefix name. `nhsfake:Specialty`, `specialty:specialtyid`, `specialty:specialtyname`

Comment: damn, I'm dumb. Thank you very much!